# c# combobox edit - best practice

Tags: c#

I am using c# combo box controls where I would like to allow the users to enter new values. i.e I have the DropDownStyle = DropDown. For example, I have a combo box that allows users to select/enter the country code. While loading the form I set the dataset for the combobox by querying database for the code and displaytext for the countries. User can either select an existing country code or enter a new one. Please don't ask why I can't pre populate the combo box with all possible country codes as it is a finite set with infrequent changes, it is the customer requirement and besides there are several controls like this (test center, etc).

Now the way currently the combo box works is, if the user types in a new entry, I add the new value to the database and refresh the dataset. I do this so the new entry has a proper unique code in the database. This slows down the application a bit though it is not a frequent operation. Currently I also set the AutoCompleteMode property to SuggestAppend. This is to prevent users from adding a duplicate entry or entering misspellings of existing entries.

What is the best practice in this regard? Is it better to add new entries in memory and add them to the database at a later stage? It is a multi-user application and it is also possible someone else could also be adding the same entry though it is rare.

This is a windows forms application running on WinXP possibly running on Win7 someday, both 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing it correctly by adding new entries to the database and refreshing the `datasource`. Of course before you add, you need to check that the entry doesn't already exist in the database, as its possible it could have been added by another user after their last request was made. It shouldn't take too long.. but that depends on your result set. I use this technique for a combobox in my application with currently 314 entries, similar settings, and it works just fine. No questions or complaints from the client (yet). Maybe your downtime is not in the technique, but in the implementation or elsewhere.

If you were to have many entries (thousands or whatever that may be), perhaps another solution would be more appropriate. But for your purpose, this should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Because the user doesn't need to care about the insert into the database, you could make that part happen asynchronously to the main UI. That would prevent the slow down of the UI. If you're using .NET 4, look into the TPL libraries for this.

As for how you can handle concurrency, I recommend you use a procedure in the database that you would use that would use a transaction (or equivalent) to select first, and if nothing is present, insert. Either case, it could return the unique ID still.

Answer (score -1):

couldnt you add a try catch that checks the current listings against the newlyt added one?

if something exists
do not insert
else insert

Comment: No need for a `try catch`, an `if` clause should suffice here.